# Java regex contradiction in Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: java, android, regex

I have to match some string against `"Phone_123":""` where any number instead of `123` is acceptable. I am using regex

```
\\\"Phone_[0-9]+\\\":\\\"\\\"
```

and it matches the string ([in the yellow rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpIvl.png))

[image: AS_2.3.3] when I try it in `Android Studio 2.3.3`. But when I try the same `regex` against the same string under debug it doesn't match! What is the problem with my regex?

Comment: Use `find()` rather than `matches()` when looking for regex matches inside longer strings (`matches()` only returns a match if the whole string matches the pattern).

Comment: Will try, but initially I have tried `replaceAll` and it doesn't work under debug too...

Comment: And another point: do not use `\\\"`. Use just `\"` because `"` is not a special regex metacharacter, no need to escape it.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: You answer is correct, thanks!